# Changing SVG-Icon when Active

Tags: jquery, svg, icons

I'm pretty new to this jQuery-Thing, so sorry for possible dump question in advance. I searched already, but could't find any help on my specific problem.

So. I try to chance my menuicon (hamburgericon, the popular stuff, you know) when active to a close-icon. i found this: http://css-tricks.com/swapping-svg-icons/

```
 $(".expand-link")
            .on("click", function() {
                $(this).find("use").attr("xlink:href", "#closeicon");
            })
            .on("mouseleave", function() {
                $(this).find("use").attr("xlink:href", "#menuicon");
            });
```

Now, what i want is that on the first click on the Menuicon, it changes to the Close-Icon. On the second click, on the icon or elsewhere, it changes the closeicon back to the menuicon.

using the "click"-event twice doesn't work, i tried different mouseevents, but none of them helped either.

Answer (score 0):

create a flag variable and change its state on each click so you know whic URL to set. E.g.

```
flag = true
$(".expand-link")
            .on("click", function() {
                if (flag)
                $(this).find("use").attr("xlink:href", "#closeicon");
                else
                $(this).find("use").attr("xlink:href", "#menuicon");
                flag = !flag;
           });
```

E.g. [this](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/2hrwawz9/1/)

Comment: Hm, that almost works, the only problem is that i have to click on the icon again to change it back. if i click anywhere else on the page, the icon stays the same.

probably i just have to set a div over the whole page?

Comment: i just realised the problem is connected to a off-canvas-navigation, so my problem seems to be a bit bigger then just that. i might ask some guys i know to help me directly. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Please post a Fiddle.

.find("use") => Are you sure there is a <use></use>? If you want to select by class, use ".find('.use')"

btw - you can check the attr by

```
.on('click', function() {
    if($(this).find("use").attr("xlink:href") === '#closeicon') {
       // do this
    } else {
        // do that
    }
 });
```

Comment: give me a few seconds, i will set up a fiddle

Comment: uf, so, i don't know what i'm doing wrong in fiddle, but it's not working realy. i made it anyway, eventually you can see what i am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/2hrwawz9/


Edit: Yes, the use-tag is there. i got that swaping-code form css-tricks.com. this is their codepen: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Dqpib